# Php lengthy if statements and permutations

Tags: php

Is there any method to simplify a lengthy if statement such as below. Even Switch case is very lengthy:

```
$day1
$day2

if ($day1 ==‘Monday’ && $day2 ==‘Monday’) {
//code
}
elseif ($day1 ==‘Monday’ && $day2 ==‘Tuesday’) {
// code
}
elseif ($day1 == ‘Monday’ && $day2 == ‘Wednesday’) {
//code
}
```

…covering all possible combinations of $day1 and $day2

Help and tips greatly appreciated.

**Update
The problem has arisen out a bad database design. At the time, I thought it was a good idea. I have a table which records attendance data for a school as follows

| Id | School_id | Date | Student_id | MonAM | MonPM | TueAM | TuePM | WedAM | WedPM | ThuAM | ThuPM | FriAM | FriPM | SatAM | SatPM | SunAM | SunPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-11-28 | 1 | / | / | / | / | / | / | / | / | / | / |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-11-28 | 2 | / | / | N | / | / | / | / | / | / | / |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-11-28 | 3 | N | / | N | / | / | / | N | / | / | / |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-11-28 | 4 | / | N | / | / | / | N | / | / | / | N |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-11-28 | 5 | N | / | / | N | N | / | N | / | N | / |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 1 | 2022-12-05 | 1 | / | / | N | / | / | N | / | / | N | N |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 1 | 2022-12-05 | 2 | N | / | N | / | / | / | / | / | / | / |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | 1 | 2022-12-05 | 3 | / | N | N | N |  | N | / | N | / | N |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | 1 | 2022-12-05 | 4 | / | / | / | / | N | / | / | / | / | N |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | 1 | 2022-12-05 | 5 | N | / | N |  | / | N |  | N | N | / |  |  |  |  |

/ = present, N = absent
When attendance data is saved, my code checks for the date of Monday of the current week based on the current date. This date is saved along with attendance data. In other words, attendance data is saved on a weekly basis on db.
For the most part, this works very well.

However, when it comes to generating attendance reports, the db design makes it difficult to find data mid-week or from, let’s say Tuesday of one week to Friday of another week, since the date column is always the date of Monday of week when data was saved.
My application is built on Laravel. My db query returns rows based on the Monday date of query date range. To get around the issue of mid-week data, I am using the following logic after querying db for each student.

If query result array (Laravel collection) count is 1:

Find day of query start date (ie Monday).
Find day of query end date (ie Wednesday)
Use a if statement (as above) to select only the relevant column data, ie column MonAM – WedPM

If query result array (Laravel collection) count > 1
In foreach loop, check if current array key is 1 (this is first row of result)
Find day of query start date (ie Monday).
Use a if statement (similar to above) to select only the relevant column data,

In foreach loop, check if current array is last key (this is last row)
Find day of query end date (ie Wednesday)
Use a if statement (similar to above) to select only the relevant column data

In foreach loop, if key is not first or last, then select data from all columns

Im assuming the above logic will give me accurate data for all query date ranges.

**Update. I have managed to get the desired data within given date range, but the nested if statements and switch cases is resulting in poor execution times.
Any ideas on how to make this more efficient without changing db design

My current code is (contracted):

```
$start_date = $request->start_date; // eg 29/11/22
$end_date = $request->end_date; // eg 03/12/22
$dateToCheck = new DateTimeImmutable($start_date);
if ($dateToCheck->format('D') === 'Mon') {
   $WeekStart = $start_date;
} else {
$WeekStart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('previous monday', strtotime($start_date)));
}
$students_arr = array_merge($student_arr1, $student_arr2); //array of student ids

foreach ($students_arr as $arr) {
    $attendance = SchoolAttendanceData::where("student_id", $arr)->where("school_id", $school_id)->whereBetween("date", [$WeekStart, $end_date])->orderBy("date", "asc")->get();
    $codes=array();
    if ($attendance->isNotEmpty()) {
        if (count($attendance) === 1) {
            foreach($attendance as $key => $attend) {
                if ($attend->date == $WeekStart) {
                    if ($day_start == 'Monday' && $day_end == 'Monday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Monday' && $day_end == 'Tuesday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Monday' && $day_end == 'Wednesday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Monday' && $day_end == 'Thursday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Monday' && $day_end == 'Friday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Monday' && $day_end == 'Saturday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Monday' && $day_end == 'Sunday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Tuesday' && $day_end == 'Tuesday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Tuesday' && $day_end == 'Wednesday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Tuesday' && $day_end == 'Thursday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Tuesday' && $day_end == 'Friday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Tuesday' && $day_end == 'Saturday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Tuesday' && $day_end == 'Sunday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Wednesday' && $day_end == 'Wednesday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Wednesday' && $day_end == 'Thursday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Wednesday' && $day_end == 'Friday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Wednesday' && $day_end == 'Saturday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Wednesday' && $day_end == 'Sunday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Thursday' && $day_end == 'Thursday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Thursday' && $day_end == 'Friday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Thursday' && $day_end == 'Saturday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Thursday' && $day_end == 'Sunday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Friday' && $day_end == 'Friday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Friday' && $day_end == 'Saturday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Friday' && $day_end == 'Sunday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Saturday' && $day_end == 'Saturday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Saturday' && $day_end == 'Sunday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                    } elseif ($day_start == 'Sunday' && $day_end == 'Sunday') {
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                        $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                    }
                } else {
                    $day_of_week2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $end_date)->format('l');
                    switch ($day_of_week2) {
                        case "Monday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                          break;
                        case "Tuesday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                          break;
                        case "Wednesday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                          break;
                        case "Thursday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                            break;
                        case "Friday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            ...
                        case "Saturday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            ...
                        case "Sunday":
                            ...
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach($attendance as $key => $attend) {
                if ($attendance->keys()->first() === $key) { //first item in array
                    $day_of_week = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start_date)->format('l');
                    switch ($day_of_week) {
                        case "Monday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                            ...
                        case "Tuesday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                            ...
                        case "Wednesday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->WedAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->WedPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                            ...
                        case "Thursday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->ThuAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->ThuPM;
                            ...
                        case "Friday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->FriAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->FriPM;
                            ...
                        case "Saturday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->SatAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->SatPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                        case "Sunday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->SunAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->SunPM;
                        default:
                      }
                }
                if ($attendance->keys()->last() === $key) { //last item in array
                    $day_of_week2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $end_date)->format('l');
                    switch ($day_of_week2) {
                        case "Monday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                        case "Tuesday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                        case "Wednesday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                            ...
                        case "Thursday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                            ...
                        case "Friday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                            ...
                        case "Saturday":
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TueAM;
                            $codes[] = $attend->TuePM;
                            ...
                        case "Sunday":
                            ...
                        default:
                    }
                }
                if ($key != $attendance->keys()->last() || $key != $attendance->keys()->first()) {
                    $codes[] = $attend->MonAM;
                    $codes[] = $attend->MonPM;
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bite the bullet and fix the design of the DB now. You are likely to run into other difficulties in addition to this one.

Comment: The original design was to save diskspace. Eg current design contains 2k rows, If I change db to make it as normal, rows become 10k. And this is just 3 months data.

Comment: 10k rows is nothing for a database. Iif it were 2 billion rows then there might be hesitation but even that isn't too much really. Space is not an excuse for a properly normalized DB.

Answer (score 0):

You have laravel at your disposal and you might as well do this kind of stuff in your `Model`. I expect your input days ($day1, $day2) are not day of week inputs, but actual dates (like '2022-11-30').

You could add something like this to the Model:

```
public function getInRange(Carbon $start, Carbon $end) {
    $dt = $start->lt($this->Date) ? $start : $this->Date;
    $internalEnd = $end->subDays(7)->gt($this->Date) ? $this->Date->addDays(7) : $end;
    $output = [];

    while($dt->lt($internalEnd)) {
        $output[] = [
            'day' => $dt,
            'AM' => $this->{$dt->shortEnglishDayOfWeek.'AM'},
            'PM' => $this->{$dt->shortEnglishDayOfWeek.'PM'},
        ];

        $dt = $dt->addDay();
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Then, in the controller, or where you have the collection of Models:

```
$collection->flatMap(fn($entry) => $entry->getInRange($start, $end));
```

Of course, I still know little of your actual code, so you might need to tweak some stuff. You could also pass a closure to getInRange to format the data like you need it if you want the function to be more flexible,... There are a lot of options.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will have a go. I am by no means a laravel expert, or developer for that matter, but will give it a go. But I am slightly confused by this part $collection->flatMap(fn($entry) => $entry->getInRange($start, $end)); The collection would be the model itself?

Comment: I suppose you use something like `TimeRegistration::get()` in combination with any where clauses to retrieve the data from your database. The `$collection` variable would be the result of that operation.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to implement your code. In any case, I think it may be unsuitable for my problem. I have added more of my code to give further example of this issue. Please help :)